# Should we cover TV Series here?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Final TV Decision](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/final-tv-decision)

There's the whole thing with [TV Buffs](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2026/tv-buffs), they're still pretty far off from getting a beta, I'd say.

So do we take an active stand to encourage questions about TV, so that the proposal to merge the two gains more ground, or do we avoid treading on our couch slouching friends' toes? (no offense meant to home theater goers)

And then between 'hell yeah' and 'not at all' we have gray areas: what of high-production series (e.g. frigging game of awesome thrones?)